# Azure SQL - creating an autogenerating id with a constraint causing issues for powerapps

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, powerapps

When using the below SQL, I get the error "Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'."

```
SQL statement with key and autogenerate id:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stopwords](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Stopword] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
 [Timestamp] [nvarchar](17) NULL,
 [Created by] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StopwordsId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I need an autogenerating id so that I can write to the table using PowerApps.  Without the constraints, PowerApps will not recognize the autogenerating ID and allow me to use the table.  I think once I get the constraint in place, I will be able to get PowerApps connected properly.  I am following instructions from this video https://youtu.be/193b7T_p35M?t=9m56s and at 10 min she discusses the importance of the autogenerating key.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerApps you only need a primary key in your SQL table, so you can use a simpler version of your create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stopwords] (
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Stopword] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
  [Timestamp] [nvarchar](17) NULL,
  [Created by] [nvarchar](150) NULL
)
```

This table can be accessed by PowerApps.